What type of cactus is this?
It has shades of purple and flat oval like leaves that add onto itself as it grows higher. It has two sizes of thorns and suits the tiniest, little, slivers of Thorns when !you get too close to it. I don’t like it for the latter reason, but bought it because I loved the look of it. I have to water it from the distance or my arm will end up with 50 little thorns in it. Please help me identify what type of cactus this is. 

Just a question; how long have you had this cactus and what zone are you in? Looks beautiful! ...sounds like a nightmare

Looks like Santa Rita, Purple Dwarf Prickly Pear cactus (Opuntia Violacea Basilaris Amethyst Wave).
My experience with Opuntia matches yours ... look at it cross-eyed and end up with invisible thorns. Pro tip: Use duct tape to draw those thorns out. And wear gloves if you even think of passing by.

